# I keep getting extra 0's in my calculations

Tags: c

So I'm trying to do a salary projection project and I'm stuck on one thing, I'm getting off numbers with and it gives me extra 0's in the decimal places I don't want..

```
void calc(float *salary, float *rate, float *raise, float *newsalary)
{
    *raise = *salary*(*rate);
    *newsalary = (*salary)+(*raise);
}
void rateofsalary(float *salary, float *rate)//change this function into a return 
{
    if(*salary>=0 && *salary<=30000)
        *rate = 7.0;
    else 
        if(*salary>=30000 && *salary<=40000)
            *rate = 5.5;
        else 
            if(*salary>=40000)
                *rate = 4.0;

}
```

and the output goes like this:

```
> Please enter your salary: 25000 
>The rate is: 7.00
>|     | Salary |Rate | Raise | New Salary |
>|     | 25000.00  | 7.00  | 175000.00 | 200000.00  |
> Press any key to continue . . .
```

but what I want is this:

```
> Please enter your salary: 25000 
The rate is: 7.00
>|     | Salary |Rate | Raise | New Salary |
 |     | 25000.00  | 7.00  | 1,750.00 | 26,750.00   
> Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why do I get the extra 0's?

Comment: use of pointer is correct.

Comment: Unless you are developing for Plan 9, please give a swift, hard kick to whoever taught you to use `void main()`.

Comment: I think you mean "abuse of pointer"

Comment: Note that with your code logic, a salary of `40000` falls under both the 5.5% rate and the 4.0% rate, but it will take the 5.5% rate because that one appears first.

Comment: You don't need to pass everything as a pointer. Eliminate the cases where you are not modifying the parameter and the code becomes much more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of RateOfSalary function, add:

```
*rate /= 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, what you are getting is the correct answer.

Your salary is 25000 and rate is 7. Multiplying gives 175000 that is your raise.